# Android writing to file and saving to PC

Tags: android, file

I am trying to save some data to a file and then wish to get that file on my pc in order to analyze it. I am pretty sure the data gets written to the file but I can't seem to find the file anywhere on my phone. Any suggestions on how I could get that file to my pc in order to properly analyze it?
Here is the code I am using to write to the file:

```
try {

                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                String a = dX+"    "+dY+"    "+dZ+"   "+linear_acceleration[0]+"    "+linear_acceleration[1]+"    "+linear_acceleration[2]+"    "+acc;


                a = a + "\n";

                fos.write(a.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Send it yourself by eMail. Or drop it on DropBox (so, it will automatically be retrieved on your PC).

Comment: File path: /data/data/com.yourpackagename/files/FILE_NAME

Comment: My phone is not rooted. Is there a way to easily send the file by email from within the app?

Comment: You wrote the file to app specific internal memory. No other app, for instance a file explorer, can see it. Better writevto external memory.

Comment: My phone is a nexus 5 and has no sd card. How could I write to external memory?

Comment: Yes, you can easily attach a file taken from your storage to an eMail.

Comment: You don't need an SD card. The Nexus has internal and external memory also. Have a look at getExternalStorageDirectory() and getExternalFileDir(s)(). Use absolute paths and FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try write to external memory

```
        try {

            String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String fileName = "/mydir/filename";

            File myFile = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);

            if(!myFile.exists()){
                myFile.createNewFile();
            }


            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);                

            String a = "some text" + "\n";
            myOutWriter.append(a);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```